# How do I limit the memory usage of a specific process in linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, memory-management

I've written a program for a class that my professor will be testing in various low memory environments to see how it behaves when the program runs out of memory. Is there a way I can simulate the execution in a low memory environment without creating a virtual machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use [ulimit](http://lopsa.org/node/1755)

> ulimit can be used to limit memory utilization (among other things)
>
> Here is an example of setting memory usage so low that `/bin/ls` (which is larger than `/bin/cat`) no longer works, but `/bin/cat` still works.
>
> ```
> $ ls -lh /bin/ls /bin/cat
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25K May 24 2008 /bin/cat
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88K May 24 2008 /bin/ls
> $ date > test.txt
> $ ulimit -d 10000 -m 10000 -v 10000
> $ /bin/ls date.txt
> /bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory
> $ /bin/cat date.txt
> Thu Mar 26 11:51:16 PDT 2009
> $
> ```
>
> Note: If I set the limits to 1000 kilobytes, neither program works, because they load libraries, which increase their size. above 1000 KB.
>
> -d data segment size
>
> -m max memory size
>
> -v virtual memory size
>
> Run ulimit -a to see all the resource caps ulimits can set.

Comment: is there something that does something similar on a single user basis? I don't have the permission to make system wide changes.

Comment: @user20222: You can use ulimit at the command line or in a script in Bash.

Comment: I'm getting-- ulimit: max memory size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Comment: What exactly did you try? Post the command line you used

Comment: "ulimit -m 1000" and "ulimit -H -m 1000". I also did this: "ulimit -S -m 1000" which didn't error, but it did not enforce the memory limit for the program.

Comment: I talked to the sysadmin and I'm not sure what was wrong but he fixed the problem.

Comment: On my system, the key ulimit flag seems to be `-v` (virtual memory).  Setting `-m` doesn't seem to actually accomplish anything.

Comment: Setting -m limits the use of physical RAM on systems that enforce it. Setting -v limits the use of virtual RAM on systems that enforce it.

Comment: Note that `-m` does nothing on modern Linux kernels. You have to use `cgroups` to limit physical RAM usage these days. Unfortunately, the user interface to `cgroups` is still pretty bad.